# Google maps random creating markers around the point

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have this code,how I can modify it so that markers are created around a set point?

```
private List<Marker> mark = new ArrayList<Marker>();
public LatLng getRandomLocation() {
int radius = 7315;
LatLng point = new LatLng(59.945610, 30.315746);
List<LatLng> randomPoints = new ArrayList<>();
List<Float> randomDistances = new ArrayList<>();
Location myLocation = new Location("");
myLocation.setLatitude(point.latitude);
myLocation.setLongitude(point.longitude);
//This is to generate 10 random points
for(int i = 130; i<150; i++) {
double x0 = point.latitude;
double y0 = point.longitude;
Random random = new Random();
// Convert radius from meters to degrees
double radiusInDegrees = radius / 111000f;
double u = random.nextDouble();
double v = random.nextDouble();
double w = radiusInDegrees * Math.sqrt(u);
double t = 2 * Math.PI * v;
double x = w * Math.cos(t);
double y = w * Math.sin(t);
// Adjust the x-coordinate for the shrinking of the east-west distances
double new_x = x / Math.cos(y0);
double foundLatitude = new_x + x0;
double foundLongitude = y + y0;
LatLng randomLatLng = new LatLng(foundLatitude, foundLongitude);
randomPoints.add(randomLatLng);
Location l1 = new Location("");
l1.setLatitude(randomLatLng.latitude);
l1.setLongitude(randomLatLng.longitude);
randomDistances.add(l1.distanceTo(myLocation));
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arts);
String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.visible(true)
.draggable(false)
.title(randomStr)
.position(randomLatLng)
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.test)));
mark.add(marker);
Log.e("marker", String.valueOf(mark.size()));
}
//Get nearest point to the center
int indexOfNearestPointToCentre = randomDistances.indexOf(Collections.min(randomDistances));
return randomPoints.get(indexOfNearestPointToCentre);
}
```

I need for example ~ 30 markers to be created around the desired point, with different scatter within eg ~ 15 kilometers
now they are created as if by a line from south to north

> Sorry For my bad English,I am Russian, and sorry for my bad code,I
>   post this from telephone.

Comment: What's the problem, you are already creating random latLng?

Comment: @IsraeldelaCruz, they are created as if by a line from south to north, not circle

Answer (score 0):

Generate random angles up to 360 deg.

```
double angle = random.nextDouble()*Math.PI*2;
```

Generate random radius within max radius.

```
double randomRadius = radius*random.nextDouble();
```

Calculate relative point

```
double relativeX = Math.cos(angle)*randomRadius;
double relativeY = Math.sin(angle)*randomRadius;
```

Add the relative point to the center

```
LatLng randomLatLng = new LatLng(point.latitude + relativeX, point.longitude + relativeY);
```

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/J04A-YTXJt_H7g i do this,but have any error...i don understand how fix it...

Comment: I could not find your center before. I've edited it now assuming point is the center.

Comment: My center is LatLng point = new LatLng(59.945610, 30.315746); I work with it coordinates